# Equation Writing Help (Age Problem)

Tags: linear-algebra

A mother's age is $8$ times older than her son. When her son's age is half ($\frac{1}{2}$) of mother's current age, the sum of their ages is $60$. What was the mother's age when her son was born?

I only could write that $M = 8S$, $t$ = passed time.

$$S + t = \frac {M}{2}$$

$$S + t + M= 60$$

$$\frac{M}{2} +M = 60$$

$$2M = 120$$

$$M = 60$$

---

**EDIT:** We can easily find mother out.

$$M = 8S, S + t = \frac {M}{2}, M = 40$$

Now we need to know what her son's age is.

$$M = 8S, 40 = 8S, S = 5$$

Why is it wrong? The right answer seems $18$, which I didn't get why.

Comment: How come so many of those questions are showing up currently ?

Comment: I believe that I've gone too wrong.

Comment: Your mistake is that $2\times (\frac M2 + M)$ is not equal to $2M$.

Comment: @krirkrirk What do you mean? and why?

Comment: Well I doubt that in $10$ seconds you had the time to think about what I just said. I'm pretty sure you can understand why I said that if you give it a little try.

Comment: Another age problem lol

Comment: @Zac I feel how you feel LOL!

Comment: Can anyone take a look?

Comment: I still didn't get it If someone explains how to, I'd be grateful. We can find $M = 40$ easily, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit since OP just edited the question*

So $M = 8S$. We have $$S+t = \frac{M}{2} \iff t = \frac M2-S$$ 
and thus the son's age will be half the mother's current age in $\frac M2 -S$ years.

The sum is then $60$ so $$\frac M2 + M + (\frac M2 -S) = 60$$

Indeed, the son's age is then $\frac M2$ and the mother's age $M + (\frac M2 - S)$.

Thus $$2M-S = 60$$

Now using $M=8S$, you should be able to conclude.

Comment: Can you explain this step : $S+t = \frac{M+t}{2} \iff t = M-2S$? Why isn't it $S+t = \frac{M}{2} \iff t = M-2S$ The question says mother's current age.

Comment: Jesus, you replied in $10$ seconds again. This shows that you do not try to understand by yourself at all. I'm not interested in helping you if you don't show any effort.

Comment: I already showed my effort?

Comment: The question says mother's current age. Why is it $M+t$?

Comment: You edited the question to say *current* age $2$ minutes ago. Don't try and pretend it's there from the beginning.......

Comment: This answer helped me. However, I just didn't get why $M+t$

Comment: You may see my edit.

Comment: Good edit! I'm able to understand it right now.

Comment: Also for other questions, should we try eliminating the variable $t$ first?

Comment: Yes, you should write $t$ in terms of $S $ and $M $.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement is very poorly written, and the edit seems to make it worse. The first and second sentences must refer to two different points in time. There's no way to be 8 times and 2 times someone's age on the same day.  The first sentence refers to today and the second to some other time (which must be in the future). So, just taking the second sentence, all by itself, we find that the son's age plus twice his age is 60. He's 20 and his mother is 40. She was 20 when he was born.

The first sentence is just a source of confusion. The problem doesn't ask his age, today, fortunately. Assuming he wasn't born on his mother's birthday, she will turn 24 while he's still 3.

Comment: I agree it's poorly written ; but I think it should be interpreted as : today, the mother's age is $8$ times her son's age. When her son will be half of the nowadays mother's age, then the sum of their actual ages will be $60$. The solution is then : the mother is $32$ and her son $4$.

Comment: @rkrirkrirk your interpretation of what the problem really asks is more plausible than mine.